# SQL Select Query on Date/Time column strange behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am having an odd issue with a select statement in SQL Server Express, hopefully someone can shed some light on why I'm experiencing this behavior as well as the right way to do it.

When I run this query it returns exactly what I would expect:

```
SELECT 
    Action, TimeOccurred, UserName, IPv4From, ShareName, 
    FullFilePath, NewPathName, FromServer 
FROM 
    File_System_Profiles 
WHERE
    Action LIKE '%create%' 
    AND (TimeOccurred >= '04/27/2017')
```

All those entries from 4/27 and anything after that.

When I run this query it returns 0 results which is extremely odd since there are entries for 4/27 in the previous query's results:

```
SELECT 
    Action, TimeOccurred, UserName, IPv4From, ShareName, 
    FullFilePath, NewPathName, FromServer 
FROM 
    File_System_Profiles 
WHERE
    Action LIKE '%create%' 
    AND (TimeOccurred = '04/27/2017')
```

All I removed was the > between the = and the date and I get no results. I can clearly see when I run the first query that there are results where 04/27/2017 is the date that something occurred. If the first query didn't work I would assume there was a problem with my date format of `MM/DD/YYYY` and what is actually in the column `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but since the first one works it seems logical that the second one should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem of the date format. As you mentioned, you are using Date format as `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` so you should know that the value `"04/27/2017"` will be taken as `"04/27/2017 00:00:00"` when used in the comparison.

I assume that you have no record where the value in date field is `"04/27/2017 00:00:00"` and that is why when you use `=` operator, it does not match any record. However, the operator `>=` picks the records where hour:minute:second part of the date exist. As an example "04/27/2017 01:10:00" is greater than "04/27/2017 00:00:00" and therefore the `>` operator fetches those records.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, always use ISO standard formats for comparison.  Your code should look more like this:

```
where Action LIKE '%create%' AND 
      TimeOccurred = '2017-04-27'
```

Nauman explained the problem, which is the time component on `TimeOccurred`.  You can solve this in various ways.  One method is to convert to date.  Something like this:

```
where Action LIKE '%create%' AND 
      cast(TimeOccurred as date) = '2017-04-27'
```

Depending on the database, the `cast()` might be replaced by `trunc()` or `date_trunc()` or something else.

However, I prefer this version:

```
where Action LIKE '%create%' AND 
      TimeOccurred >= '2017-04-27' AND
      TimeOccurred < '2017-04-28'
```

It gets to the heart of the problem.  And -- better yet -- SQL optimizers can make use of an index.

Comment: I really appreciate your response, I marked Nauman as the answer as I did not realize it was taking the value of '04/27/2017' at '04/27/2017 00:00:00'.  Thank you for your recommendations, I think I am going to go with your preferred method but just include the time in addition to the date so I can get more granular in the query if I like.